# Git failed to encode from UTF-8 to UTF-16LE-BOM

Tags: git, utf-8, utf-16

I have a lot of legacy Windows Resource Files (*.rc) in my repository. Initially they had UTF-8, ASCII, UTF-16 or other encoding. Also there were no .gitattributes in my repo, so git wasn't able to produce diff for UTF-16 files and treated them as binary.

In my `dev` branch I've converted all of *.rc files to UTF-16LE-BOM with CRLF line endings and added .gitattributes with `**/*.rc text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16LE-BOM eol=CRLF`. (I've converted all files to UTF-16 to simply use *.rc mask and not list all the files explicitly.)

But when I clone my repo and try `git checkout` to `dev` branch I see a lot of errors `failed to encode '...' from UTF-8 to UTF-16LE-BOM`, so it looks like git treats them as UTF-8 regardless of .gitattributes contents. Also after checkout all of the *.rc files become corrupted.

Before:

```cpp
#include <winver.h>

// Version Information
#ifndef _DEBUG
```

After:

```cpp
#include <winver.h>
਍ഀഀ
// Version Information
਍⌀椀昀渀搀攀昀 开䐀䔀䈀唀䜀ഀഀ
```

Also If I type `git status` after checkout, git shows `failed to encode '...' from UTF-16LE-BOM to UTF-8`.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'⌀椀昀渀搀攀昀 开䐀䔀䈀唀䜀ഀഀ'.encode('utf-16-le').decode('utf-16-be')` results to `'#ifndef _DEBUG\r\r'` (and, oddly enough, `'⌀椀昀渀搀攀昀 开䐀䔀䈀唀䜀ഀഀ'.encode('utf-16-be').decode('utf-16-le')` gives the same string `'#ifndef _DEBUG\r\r'`).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for the .gitattributes file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) has examples for configuring the working tree encoding of UTF-16 files which (1) have a byte order mark (BOM), or (2) lack one.  To paraphrase:

If the UTF-16 file has a BOM, set `working-tree-encoding=UTF-16`.  Git apparently inspects the BOM to distinguish little endian from big endian.

If the UTF-16 file lacks a BOM, set `working-tree-encoding=UTF-16LE` or `working-tree-encoding=UTF-16BE` depending on the text encoding in use.

The encoding type `UTF-16LE-BOM` is never mentioned in the documentation; however, Git supports encodings available when you run `iconv --list` from a terminal (or from Git Bash on Windows).  `UTF-16LE-BOM` does not appear as a supported encoding on either Ubuntu 18.04 or Windows 10.